# htaccess redirect to certain subdirectory if none given

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect base URL to certain subdirectory, only if the base URL is requested. E.g. Redirect `www.example.com` to `www.example.com/en`. But if the URL already contains a subdirectory (eg. `www.example.com/de`), no redirection should take place.

How can this be done via `.htaccess`?

Comment: Is `/en` a physical directory on the filesystem? Or just a URL-path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite at the *top* of the root `.htaccess` file to redirect the root-directory-only to `/en`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^$ /en [R=302,L]
```

But note that if `/en` is a physical directory on the filesystem then you should be redirecting to `/en/` (with a trailing slash), not `/en`. Otherwise, mod_dir will trigger a second redirect to append the trailing slash.